# How to read Text property of ScintillaNET class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scintilla

I am trying to build a simple Python Editor with ScintillaNET and am now trying to return the input.
I have a class `PythonScriptView`:

```
public class PythonScriptView : Scintilla
{
    // setup python syntax highlighting
}
```

and a `Form` which consists of a `PythonScriptView` component and an OK button. Inside this class I want to build a function which shows the form and returns the Text property of my `PythonScriptView`. I did this for another small dialog window which uses a textbox as input field and are now trying the same with the scintilla editor:

```
    public string GetUserInput()
    {
        ShowDialog();
        return ScriptView.Text; // ScriptView is of Type PythonScriptView
    }
```

When I am running the app I get the following error message:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in ScintillaNET.dll`

Does anyone know how to solve this? How else can I read the Text property?

**Edit:**

Seems like I cannot access *any* properties or methods from this class

Comment: Why downvote? Is this really such a stupid question? I even tried literally what it says in the [docs](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET#retrieve-text):
`var text = scintilla.GetTextRange(0, Math.Min(256, scintilla.TextLength));` which raises the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this same issue and it appears that due to the way ScintillaNET works you are not able to access any properties once the element is disposed do to the form closing. I found a work around by adding the following event and property to my Form.

```
private void FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    CachedText = scintilla.Text;
}

public string CachedText { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Eventually, I also found out it had something to do with the form and found a similar workaround with an event handler. Not as clean and generic as yours though :)